# I Encounter error when SelectingSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml

**EDIT:** I think the reason is because of "UniversalShipment" xmlns. There is a link but i remove it for confidentiality.  I can't pass through that node. help

This is my XML.

```
<UniversalInterchange xmlns="" version="1.0">
      <Header>
        <SenderID>1</SenderID>
        <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
      </Header>
      <Body>
        <UniversalShipment xmlns="" version="1.1">
          <Shipment>   
            <CustomizedFieldCollection>
                <CustomizedField>
                  <Key>Documents Checked</Key>
                  <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                  <Value>false</Value>
                </CustomizedField>
                <CustomizedField>
                  <Key>Date Completed</Key>
                  <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
                  <Value></Value>
                </CustomizedField>
            </CustomizedFieldCollection>
          </Shipment>
        </UniversalShipment>
      </Body>
    </UniversalInterchange>
```

I received null when getting singlenode. But when i try "Body" only in single node it add to bottom. if i tried to add it to UniversalShipment "Body/UniversalShipment" it encounters and error.

```
   XmlDocument doc=new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("sample.xml");
    XmlNode customizedNode = doc.CreateElement("CustomizedField");
                XmlNode keyNode = doc.CreateElement("Key");
                XmlNode dataNode = doc.CreateElement("DataType");
                XmlNode valueNode = doc.CreateElement("Value");
                keyNode.InnerText = "hi";
                dataNode.InnerText = "hello";
                valueNode.InnerText = "bye";
                customizedNode.AppendChild(keyNode);
                customizedNode.AppendChild(dataNode);
                customizedNode.AppendChild(valueNode);
                doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/CustomizedFieldCollection").AppendChild(customizedNode);
    doc.Save("sample.xml");
```

Comment: Start the expression from root or '/' document element something like this: UniversalInterchange/Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/CustomizedFieldCollection. I have not tried it but it should work.

Comment: @seesharpconcepts "UniversalInterchange/Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/CustomizedFieldCollection" i still encounter an error. I think it is because of xmlns. there is a link provided but i remove it. i can't show the link to you.

Comment: Above Xpath witll work when no namespaces are declared. Initialize XmlNamespaceManager and pass it as argument to Select methods. Link to msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have default namespaces you will need to use an XmlNamespaceManager - however, you have two default namespaces so it's a little more complicated.

As you have completely removed the namespace URIs from your question I've invented my own:

```
<UniversalInterchange xmlns="firstdefaultnamespace" version="1.0">
  <Header>
    <SenderID>1</SenderID>
    <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <UniversalShipment xmlns="seconddefaultnamespace" version="1.1">
      <Shipment>   
        <CustomizedFieldCollection>
            <CustomizedField>
              <Key>Documents Checked</Key>
              <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
              <Value>false</Value>
            </CustomizedField>
            <CustomizedField>
              <Key>Date Completed</Key>
              <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
              <Value></Value>
            </CustomizedField>
        </CustomizedFieldCollection>
      </Shipment>
    </UniversalShipment>
  </Body>
</UniversalInterchange>
```

If your first default namespace has a URI of `firstdefaultnamespace` and your second default namespace has a URI of `seconddefaultnamespace` you can do this:

```
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("ns1", "firstdefaultnamespace");
    ns.AddNamespace("ns2", "seconddefaultnamespace");

    doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:Body/ns2:UniversalShipment/ns2:Shipment/ns2:CustomizedFieldCollection", ns).AppendChild(customizedNode);
```

However, you will have problems when you save your XML with the new XmlNodes - you are not creating it with any namespace so it will be saved with a new default namespace, which will override the default namespace on the `UniversalShipment` element.

I would strongly suggest you read more about XML namespacing.

If you want to create your elements and keep them within the inner default namespace, you'll need to do something like this:

```
    const string FirstNamespaceUri = "firstdefaultnamespace";
    const string SecondNamespaceUri = "seconddefaultnamespace";
    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("ns1", FirstNamespaceUri);
    ns.AddNamespace("ns2", SecondNamespaceUri);

    XmlNode customizedNode = doc.CreateElement("CustomizedField", SecondNamespaceUri);
    XmlNode keyNode = doc.CreateElement("Key", SecondNamespaceUri);
    XmlNode dataNode = doc.CreateElement("DataType", SecondNamespaceUri);
    XmlNode valueNode = doc.CreateElement("Value", SecondNamespaceUri);
    keyNode.InnerText = "hi";
    dataNode.InnerText = "hello";
    valueNode.InnerText = "bye";
    customizedNode.AppendChild(keyNode);
    customizedNode.AppendChild(dataNode);
    customizedNode.AppendChild(valueNode);

    doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:Body/ns2:UniversalShipment/ns2:Shipment/ns2:CustomizedFieldCollection", ns).AppendChild(customizedNode);
```

Comment: @Reynan if this answers your question, can you accept it as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

XPath expression is not formed correctly in you case. Check this link for XPath guide: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Working Xpath:
    doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Body/UniversalShipment/Shipment/CustomizedFieldCollection").AppendChild(customizedNode);

If namespaces are specified in the XML, XmlNamespaceManager can be passed to XmlNode.SelectSingleNode as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx)!